# Multiple user testing android app

Tags: android, facebook, hash, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have used `facebook SDK` to login in my `android` application and I registered it with my facebook account. It works perfectly if I try to log in with my personal facebook accout (the one with which I registered the app) but if my friend tries to access with his facebook account we have this error:

"Invalid key hash. The key hash KEYHASH does not match any stored key hashes. Configure your app key hashes at [link to my app](http://developers.facebook.com/apps/id). "

I can't understand why. I gave him all permission adding him as administrator in the control panel. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

How is the app being distributed, manually via apk or Google Play Store?

It can make a difference, you actually need 2 different api keys or hash keys as facebook calls them.  In your manifest your have something like

`<meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/fb_app_id" />`

The value of @string/fb_app_id for your development / debugging version and then a value for the release version, if your publishing the app, like on the Google Play Store.

I actually have 2 hash key values defined on the [Facebook Developers website](https://developers.facebook.com/apps)  for my application, one for development and one for an actual release.